# laravel5 view with a starnge error

Tags: php, laravel, view

i have this view and when i request it it shows me a strange error, well strange for me i guess.
my create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {!! Form::open([action('PropertiesController@update', $property->id), 'files'=>true]) !!}
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! From::label('category', 'category') !!}
                {!! Form::select('category', {{ $categories }},['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('city', 'located city') !!}
                {!! Form::select('city', {{ $citys }},['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('street', 'Street adress: ') !!}
                {!! Form::text('street', 'Adress', ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::file('images') !!}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('description', 'Add description') !!}
                {!! Form::textarea('description', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::submit('Done', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
            </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>

@stop
```

the error is:

> ErrorException in 83c90d4b665ecd8385b3b6b2e7203d1ef06a1339.php line 8:
>   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' (View:
>   /home/vagrant/Code/housing/resources/views/properties/create_property.blade.php)

please help am stuck :(

Comment: you can go to the folder `storage/logs/laravel.log` and go to the last line where it show a timestamp (example `[2017-01-31 15:21:38]`) and see the error

Comment: yeah i already did that but i don't see how a '<' is a syntax error on a view file??? :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use blade syntax within blade syntax, which you don't need to do.

```
{!! Form::select('category', {{ $categories }},['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

It can simply be

```
{!! Form::select('category', $categories, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

You've done it in a couple locations, so make sure to fix them all up.  You'll notice the error mentions line 8, which is the line immediately after this error occurs.